# No se puede editar en un editor de solo lectura . Visual Estudio Code

Tags: vscode

Tengo un problema con Visual Studio Code. He instalado la extensión SFTP y al querer editar cualquier archivo abierto con el sftp me da este mensaje. ****"No se puede editar en un editor de solo lectura "**** No me deja cambiar nada.

Aclarar que usando el notepad ++ me funciona correctamente. Puedo leer y escribir.
Soy nuevo en el Visual Studio Code, quizás sea una tontería.